# when a git merge gets the same line from two different parents, which one gets blamed?

Tags: git, git-merge

If I change something in a feature branch, and then change it back, and then merge, even though parent #1 of the merge commit doesn't have any changes to the line, it blames the commit where I changed it back instead of the original commit.  How is that calculated?

```
$ git init
$ # create a simple file
$ echo line 1 >> file.txt
$ echo line 2 >> file.txt
$ echo line 3 >> file.txt
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -minitial
$ # now create a feature branch
$ git checkout -b feature
$ # and check off some items in the file
$ nano file.txt # so that when you are done you have
$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 2 check
line 3 check
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m'check off some items'
$ # now undo something in the feature branch
$ nano file.txt # and take away one of the checks:
$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 2 check
line 3
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m'uncheck one that I checked by accident'
$ git log --pretty=oneline
7321c57f0b2e6feb35a8498efb2939eb1e4268f2 (HEAD -> feature) uncheck one that I checked by accident
eb267c857bb529ee80dd1309994fcd76d6586c12 check off some items
d027e2f7185c2287337ad275d888fc19acbf2292 initial
$ # now go to master and merge this
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --no-ff feature
$ # so now we only have one difference between this and the previous commit
$ git diff HEAD^
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index a92d664..99e5441 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 line 1
-line 2
+line 2 check
 line 3
```

HOWEVER!!!

```
$ git blame file.txt

^d027e2f .. line 1
eb267c85 .. line 2 check
7321c57f .. line 3
```

The line that has been changed, and changed back, is blamed on the commit hash where it was changed back!

I would expect to see something like

```
^d027e2f .. line 1
eb267c85 .. line 2 check
d027e2f7 .. line 3
```

I guess a similar decision has to be made when a commit on either side of a merge makes the same change.  How does it determine which parent gets blamed?  I thought it would always be parent #1. (the same one that `HEAD^` refers to)

Does it always blame the most recent commit that puts in that exact line?
If I change something in a feature branch, and then change it back in the same feature branch, I would prefer to blame the original author.

[image: non fast forward merge with commit that undoes something]

Comment: But the most recent change was still unchecking... why would you expect anything else? You can always reblame from farther back

Comment: git looks at detlas to be merged since the last common ancestor, thus the merge consists in "applying" the 3 patches that were only on the feature (since the initial is common ancestor), thus puting the modif in and out

Comment: yeah good point - lots of operations only follow the main line (like master^ will be the initial commit) and bisecting probably, so I thought it would follow that somehow. So it is the one with the latest commit date?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me how `git blame` chooses to work through the ancestry. Note that `git bisect` understands branch-and-merge only at the *graph* level, and will pursue both legs of a two-leg merge as needed, but `git blame` is looking at an individual *file*. It may or may not use the same logic as `git log` with its TREESAME test, but `git log` can be told how to simplify history in these cases, and for `git blame` it's not obvious whether that's possible, and if so what effect it has on the line-to-commit assignments that blame makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result I expected, just go like this

```
git blame --first-parent
```